# How do I print a single element from an Array in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've got an Array in an ArrayList, and I want to access each element in the Array individually to use them.
My code doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<int[]> freeSpot = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            freeSpot.add(new int[]{x, y});
        }
    }

    System.out.println(freeSpot.get(int[0]));
```

Hope somebody can help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `freeSpot.get(0)`?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freeSpot.get(0)));`

Comment: `System.out.println(freeSpot.get(0)[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
 System.out.println(freeSpot.get(x)[y]);
```

where `x` if the index of the List and `y` the index of the array.

For example:

to get the first element of the array of the first element of the list :

```
System.out.println(freeSpot.get(0)[0]);
```

to get the second element of the array of the first element of the list :

```
 System.out.println(freeSpot.get(0)[1]);
```

Comment: get(0)[1] and get(0)[2] should be get(0)[0] and get(0)[1]

Comment: I can't edit yet. lol I am also guilty of the same type of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:

```
List<Integer[]> freeSpot = new ArrayList<>();

for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        freeSpot.add(new Integer[]{x, y});
    }
}

for(Integer[] entry : freeSpot) {
    System.out.println("x: " + entry[0] + " y: " + entry[1]);
}
```